# Why text in text% not getting deleted?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to delete existing text from a text-area and insert new text but it is not working. I have following code:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define myframe (new frame%
                     [label "testing"]
                     [width 600]
                     [height 400]))
(define mytextarea (new text% ))
(new editor-canvas% 
    [parent myframe] 
    [editor mytextarea])
(define (button_fn button event)
        (begin
          (send mytextarea delete               ; does not work;
                (send mytextarea get-start-position)
                (send mytextarea get-end-position))
          (send mytextarea insert "New string inserted" 0) ; works;
          ))
(define mybutton (new button% [parent myframe]
                    [label "delete"]
                    [callback button_fn ]))
(send myframe show #t)
```

There is no error message. Where is the problem and how can it be  solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get-start-position`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._text~25%29._get-start-position%29%29) and [`get-end-position`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._text~25%29._get-end-position%29%29) return the start and end of the current *selection*; if there's no selection, then they both return the position of the cursor.

If you want to delete the whole contents of the text area, use [`last-position`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._text~25%29._last-position%29%29):

```
(send mytextarea delete 0 (send mytextarea last-position))
```

or you could use the [`erase`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._text~25%29._erase%29%29) method:

```
(send mytextarea erase) ;; deletes everything
```

Comment: I also found another method: 'select-all' then 'delete'.